# Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

Can anyone recommend a good tutorial on getting started with Google Maps for web apps, be it PHP, JavaScript (and frameworks) or ActionScript 3, please?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well one place to start with Google Maps, would be [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 11):

A good place to start would be the documentation available [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html).
Also I have created a few demo's that would help you understand how to get started. These can be found [he](http://tallymobile.com/test4.html)[re](http://tallymobile.com/test5.html).

Answer (score 4):

This page has helped me a lot! Its a great supplement to google's own documentation, with lots of examples. ALL kredit to Mike!

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

Hope it helped!

Comment: np, I just realized after posting, that your post was rather old, but hey, its never to late to get a fine link :)